# Why is my ggplot constrained?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The produced image is constrained for some reason. How can I make this in proper scale. It was working fine till yesterday. I didn't change anything and from today, the figure is stretched in.

```
library("maps")
usamap <- map_data("state")
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon( data=usamap, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
  geom_point(data=foo1,aes(x=lon,y=lat,colour=id))+
  scale_color_manual(name = "CONUS",values=cols)+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.90, 0.20))+
  ggsave("useventsmap.png")
```

Thanks/

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "proper scale"?

Comment: You mean to add coord_map()? When I added it, is now stretching outwards. Still not to scale.

Comment: I think I asked a legitimate question. Could someone please explain what I asked wrong that I am being downvoted? I gave a code, a figure and a clear question. Or am I disturbing the old boys programming club of SO that lesser minions are not allowed to enter? I atleast deserve an explanation I think.

Comment: your code is not reproducible (no data), and it's not clear what you mean by constrained, try to be more specific. That being said, I did not downvote.

Comment: I don't know the proper English word for it. I meant it is not to proper scale. This is not how a US map should look like. Thank you for clarifying though. The data is from a popular library directly. And I am adding it now.

Comment: your code has a few problems. First, it's not reproducible (try to run it in a fresh session to see the errors we get). Second, `ggsave()` should be an independent line, not added to the plot (it probably gives you an error). If you change this, and add `coord_map()`, it should work.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by independent line? It works for me.

Comment: I mean separate. Not following a `+`. Luckily for you, `ggsave()` returns nothing, so it works without error. It's not meant to be added to a plot though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the spacing for latitude and longitude to be the same for your plot, try adding

```
+ coord_map(projection = "mercator")
```

or

```
+ coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

This will help to keep your width and height in the appropriate ratio.